# Count number of childs in QTreeWidget PySide

Tags: python, pyside, maya, pyside2

i have QTreeWidget and i need to count childs depending of his father(or topLevelItem) Im trying with childCount, but im really lost

example:

[image]

```
child = QTreeWidgetItem(self.data)
itemFather.addChild(child)
                    
test = QTreeWidgetItem.childCount(itemFather)
```

Comment: Your code should do what you're asking. Please clarify your actual goal.

Comment: More normally: `count = itemFather.childCount()`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're accessing the class method to retrieve the `childCount()` but [the method documentation](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTreeWidgetItem.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem.childCount) doesn't mention the ability to pass arguments. Try accessing the instance itself like so:

```
test = itemFather.childCount()
```

or just store the children in a separate data structure and get the length when you need it.

```
children = []

child = QTreeWidgetItem(self.data)
children.append(child)
itemFather.addChild(child)
                    
test = len(children)
```